# Multiple docker compose files, with env_file specified

Tags: docker, environment-variables, dockerfile, docker-compose

I'm working on a project where I'm using docker to create a base configuration, and extending it. My base docker-compose.yml file has `links`, so I can't use the `extends` param in the extending compose file. Instead, I'm specifying multiple docker-compose files to the `docker-compose` tool.

This is working well, except that it seems that the path to the `.env` file is always relative to the first docker-compose.yml file specified, which breaks my intended functionality.

Example:

**docker-compose.yml** (lives in a common location, let's say `~/base-app`)

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
  ports:
    - "80:3000"
  links:
    - redis
redis:
  image: redis:latest
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
```

Now in a child app, I'd like to specify a `command` and `env_file`:

**docker-compose.override.yml**

```
web:
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: development
  env_file: .env
  command: node server.js
```

When I run this setup, I'd use the following command:

```
docker-compose -f ~/base-app/docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml up
```

This works well, as long as I don't specify an `env_file`. But with the `env_file` specified, I'll get an error like:

```
ERROR: Couldn't find env file: ~/base-app/.env
```

Reading the [docker-compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#env-file), it says that the env file path is relative to the docker-compose file when using the `-f` flag.

Am I missing something, or is this a bug? What would be a clean way of using an `.env` file relative to an override docker-compose file?

Comment: With multiple compose files, each file is treated as only an incomplete fragment, so the paths are relative to the base.  I don't think there is any way to make it relative to the override if they are in different directories.

Answer (score 0):

Personally what worked for me and am quiet happy is i have an empty docker-compose file at the root of all my projects that I need to cross reference between, and always set that as the first `-f` in all compose commands, and have changed all my compose files to use paths relative from the root of my solution/source where the first compose file lives.

```
/src <- root
/src/docker-compose.yml <- empty docker-compose file only specifying version
/src/api/docker-compose.yml <- docker-compose file using paths relative from /src/
/src/web/docker-compose.yml <- docker-compose file using paths relative from /src/
```

I then have some batch/powershell files that invoke docker-compose such as:

```
/** docker-compose-re-up.bat **/
docker-compose -f ../docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.yml down
docker-compose -f ../docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.yml build
docker-compose -f ../docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.yml up -d
```