# Docker compose build time args from file

Tags: docker, webpack, docker-compose, open-source, next.js

I'm aware of the variable substitutions available, where I could use a `.env` at the root of the project and that would be done, but in this case  I'm adapting an existing project, where existing `.env` file locations are expected and I would like to prevent having to have var entries on multiple files!

See [documentation](https://github.com/pnmcosta/saas-boilerplate/wiki/Changes-on-docker-support-branch) for more info, and all the code is available as WIP on the `docker-support` branch of the repo, but I'll succinctly describe the project and issue below:

#### Project structure

```
|- root
|  |- .env # mongo and mongo-express vars (not on git!)
|  |- docker-compose.yaml # build and ups a staging env
|  |- docker-compose.prod.yaml # future wip
|  |- api # the saas-api service
|     |- Dockerfile # if 'docked' directly should build production
|     |- .env # api relative vars (not on git!)
|  |- app # the saas-app service
|     |- Dockerfile # if 'docked' directly should build production
|     |- .env # api relative vars (not on git!)
```

Or see the whole thing [here](https://github.com/pnmcosta/saas-boilerplate/tree/docker-support), it works great by the way for the moment, but there's one problem with `saas-app` when building an image for staging/production that I could identify so far.

#### Issue

At build time Next.js builds a static version of the pages using webpack to do it's thing about `process.env` substitution, so it requires the actual eventual running vars to be included at docker build stage so next.js doesnt need to rebuild again at runtime and also so that I can safely spawn multiple instances when traffic requires!

I'm aware that if at runtime the same vars are not sent it will have to rebuild again defying the point of this exercise, but that's precisely what I'm trying to prevent here, to that if the wrong values are sent it's on us an not the project!

And I also need to consider Next.js BUILD ID managemement, but that's for another time/question.

#### Attempts

I've been testing with including the ARG and ENV declarations for each of the variables expected by the app on it's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/pnmcosta/saas-boilerplate/blob/docker-support/app/Dockerfile), e.g.:

```
ARG GA_TRACKING_ID=
ENV GA_TRACKING_ID ${GA_TRACKING_ID}
```

This works as expected, however it forces me to manually declare them on the [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/pnmcosta/saas-boilerplate/blob/docker-support/docker-compose.yml#L43) file, which is not ideal:

```
  saas-app:
    build:
      context: app
      args:
        GA_TRACKING_ID: UA-xXxXXXX-X
```

I cannot use variable substitution here because my root `.env` does not include this var, it's on `./app/.env`, and I also tested leaving the value empty but it is not picking it up from the `env_file` or `enviroment` definitions, which I believe is as expected.

I've [pastbinned](https://pastebin.com/NrKmJBu8) a full output of `docker-compose config` with the existing version on the repository:

Ideally, I'd like:

```
  saas-app:
    build:
      args:
        LOG_LEVEL: notice
        NODE_ENV: development
        PORT: '3000'
      context: /home/pedro/src/opensource/saas-boilerplate/app
    command: yarn start
    container_name: saas-app
    depends_on:
    - saas-api
    environment:
      ...
```

To become:

```
  saas-app:
    build:
      args:
        LOG_LEVEL: notice
        NODE_ENV: development
        PORT: '3000'
        BUCKET_FOR_POSTS: xxxxxx
        BUCKET_FOR_TEAM_AVATARS: xxxxxx
        GA_TRACKING_ID: ''
        LAMBDA_API_ENDPOINT: xxxxxxapi
        NODE_ENV: development
        STRIPEPUBLISHABLEKEY: pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        URL_API: http://api.saas.localhost:8000
        URL_APP: http://app.saas.localhost:3000
      context: /home/pedro/src/opensource/saas-boilerplate/app
    command: yarn start
    container_name: saas-app
    depends_on:
    - saas-api
    environment:
      ...
```

#### Questions

How would I be able to achieve this, if possible, but:

1. Without merging the existing `.env` files into a single root, or having to duplicate vars on multiple files.
2. Without manually declaring the values on the compose file, or having to infer them on the command e.g. `docker-compose build --build-arg GA_TRACKING_ID=UA-xXxXXXX-X`?
3. Without having to `COPY` each `.env` file during the [build stage](https://github.com/pnmcosta/saas-boilerplate/blob/docker-support/app/Dockerfile#L11), because it doesn't feel right and/or secure?
4. Maybe a `args_file` on the compose `build` options feature request for the compose team seems to me to be a valid, would you also say so?
5. Or perhaps have a root option on the compose file where you could set more than one `.env` file for variable substituion?
6. Or perhaps another solution i'm not seeing? Any ideas?
7. I wouldn't mind sending each `.env` file as a [config](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#configs-configuration-reference) or [secret](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#secrets-configuration-reference), it's a cleaner solution than splitting the compose files, is anyone running such an example for production?

Comment: Umm, maybe a variation of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55543513/271433 where a root compose file with (mongo + mongo-express) and a dedicated one for each service, hopefully I can use variable substitution then.

Comment: Nahh, don't think it will work (separate compose-files per service) cause if you look at https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#understanding-multiple-compose-files  it says "you must make sure all paths in the files are relative to the base Compose file" which probably means the .env file it loads will be relative to it too! :(

Comment: Hang on, actually ".env placed in the folder where the docker-compose command is executed (current working directory)." from https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/ and "--project-directory PATH    Specify an alternate working directory
                              (default: the path of the Compose file)" from https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/ may allow otherwise! Will have to investigate further :D

Comment: Option 7. from edit now probably is the most sensible one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to achieve a compromise that does not affect any of the existing development workflows, nor does it allow for **app** to build without env variables (a requirement that will be more crucial for production builds).

I've basically decided to reuse the internal ability of docker to read the `.env` file and use those in variable substitution on the compose file, here's an example:

```
# compose
COMPOSE_TAG_NAME=stage

# common to api and app (build and run)
LOG_LEVEL=notice
NODE_ENV=development
URL_APP=http://app.saas.localhost:3000
URL_API=http://api.saas.localhost:8000
API_PORT=8000
APP_PORT=3000

# api (run)
MONGO_URL=mongodb://saas:secret@saas-mongo:27017/saas
SESSION_NAME=saas.localhost.sid
SESSION_SECRET=3NvS3Cr3t!
COOKIE_DOMAIN=.saas.localhost
GOOGLE_CLIENTID=
GOOGLE_CLIENTSECRET=
AMAZON_ACCESSKEYID=
AMAZON_SECRETACCESSKEY=
EMAIL_SUPPORT_FROM_ADDRESS=
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY=
MAILCHIMP_REGION=
MAILCHIMP_SAAS_ALL_LIST_ID=
STRIPE_TEST_SECRETKEY=
STRIPE_LIVE_SECRETKEY=
STRIPE_TEST_PUBLISHABLEKEY=
STRIPE_LIVE_PUBLISHABLEKEY=
STRIPE_TEST_PLANID=
STRIPE_LIVE_PLANID=
STRIPE_LIVE_ENDPOINTSECRET=

# app (build and run)
STRIPEPUBLISHABLEKEY=
BUCKET_FOR_POSTS=
BUCKET_FOR_TEAM_AVATARS=
LAMBDA_API_ENDPOINT=
GA_TRACKING_ID=
```

See the updated [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/pnmcosta/saas-boilerplate/blob/docker-support/docker-compose.yml) I've also made use of [Extension fields](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields) to make sure only the correct and valid vars are sent across on build and run.

It breaks rule 1. from the question, but I feel it's a good enough compromise, because it no longer relies on the other `.env` files, that would potentically be development keys most of the time anyway!

Unfortunately we will need to mantain the compose file if the vars change in the future, and the same `.env` file has to be used for a production build, but since that will probably be done externally on some CI/CD, that does not worry much.

I'm posting this but not fully closing the question, if anyone else could chip in with a better idea, I'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to pass around and merge values in multiple .env's would you consider making one master .env and having the API and APP services inherit the same root .env?

Comment: no, app/api also support having a `.env` file on each's root (for the development workflow) and I don't want to break that behaviour. I could solve my problem by passing the `.env` file on the Dockerfile, https://github.com/pnmcosta/saas-boilerplate/blob/docker-support/app/Dockerfile#L11, but that doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: Cause eventually I did opt to have a master .env, I've plus1 you, thanks for the input :)